# Why does Ruby have both the && and 'and' operators?

Tags: ruby, operators, language-design

I understand [the difference between them](http://www.themomorohoax.com/2008/12/08/and-vs-amperand-in-ruby), but I can't work out why they're both included in the language. Surely having both just causes confusion?

Comment: They behave differently. What more reason do you need? What concrete, factual answer do you expect to get from this question? A recording of Matz's dreams at the time?

Comment: Firstly, any question about language design is going to be subjective. There are no right or wrong answers. Secondly, just because two operators behave differently is not a good reason to have both of them in a language. There are pros and cons, and the cons are more immediately obvious to me. This question was asked to find out what the pros are.

Comment: But Stack Overflow is not meant for subjective discussions. How will you possibly pick as "correct" one answer that explains "why" they exist? That they have different precedence, or that one is nice for DSLs, or rules of thumb for when to use them, are all _good_ information, but none answer the question you asked.

Answer (score 5):

Their precedence is different, so they are not equivalent.

My rule of thumb is as follows: use `&&` for logical expressions and use `and` for control flow.

#### Examples

```
# logical expressions
if user.first_name == 'Bob' && user.last_name == 'Jones'

# control flow
worker.do_this and worker.and_also_do_this_if_that_went_well
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how you use both of them?

Comment: +1 Even though I have answer that I think is relevant, I also like this (rule of thumb) distinction :)

Comment: Alistair logical would be like `if (variable1 && variable2) var3=20 end` where as control is things like `if (cond1 and cond2) do_this_function end`

Answer (score 2):

- Perl has the same doublets, even with the same precedence difference as in Ruby.
- Ruby was strongly influenced by Perl.

I believe one should look no further.

Answer (score 1):

Do go through this:
http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/language.html#andornotanddefined

Answer (score 0):

This is the best explanation I've seen:

http://avdi.org/devblog/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/